# Can gsettings be created dynamically?

Tags: linux, glib, gnome, gio, gsettings

I'm curious if gsettings can be used to store objects, or must everything be set statically? Could objects such as users objects be stored in gsettings? Could users be added and deleted with fixed properties on each user?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the [docs](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GSettings.html) they mention "relocatable" schema which you can create with `g_settings_new_with_path()`. This allows you to dynamically store 'objects' with the same schema in different locations. So you can create `/org/mysite/users/bob/` and in it have properties like `full-name` that every user 'object' would have. You would still store a list referencing them to know which schema exist. To remove them you can use `g_settings_reset()` on each key.

Comment: Sounds like its not something its meant to do. You really need a way to get a list of objects in a path. Storing an array of the objects you have in another key sounds kind of hacky. Also it sounds like it would be really hard to add updates to the schema - but I'm not 100% sure on that.

Comment: By design being relocatable adds some complications such as being able to track the schema that created them but it is supported and usable.